# cant redirect standardOutput from process

Tags: c#, process

I tried 3-4 versions and none worked for me.. I have a small exe for which i dont have the source anymore but it works good, but i still need the result string from it,

```
Process proc = new Process();
ProcessStartInfo StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
StartInfo.FileName = path + "calculate.exe";
StartInfo.Arguments = input;
StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

proc.StartInfo = StartInfo;

proc.Start();

proc.WaitForExit();

string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();

MessageBox.Show(output);
```

i get an empty MessageBox, any ideas why? When i add a breakpoint at WaitForExit, StandardOutput says that it isn't redirected or the process didn't start yet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set `RedirectStandardOutput`, not `RedirectStandardError`.
(also, make sure the process is really writing to standard out and not standard error)

Comment: Damn autocomplete! But yea even with the right one i still get empty messagebox..

Comment: @AdnanElezovic did you try it with `proc.StandardError.ReadToEnd();` too? It could be that your program outputs to stderr.

Comment: Yes! For some reason i had to redirect both outputs, and then both had content! I just wrote one part of the app so i wasnt sure which streams it outputs to.

@Gray please copy paste your answer so i can mark it.

Comment: @AdnanElezovic SLaks had already kinda wrote that in his last sentence. Feel free to mark his as correct, because that is where I got my idea.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
// This is the code for the base process
        Process myProcess = new Process();
        // Start a new instance of this program but specify the 'spawned' version.
        ProcessStartInfo myProcessStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(args[0], "spawn");
        myProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        myProcessStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        myProcess.StartInfo = myProcessStartInfo;
        myProcess.Start();
        StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;
        // Read the standard output of the spawned process. 
        string myString = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
        Console.WriteLine(myString);

        myProcess.WaitForExit();
        myProcess.Close();
```

Source : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput.aspx)